# Works in Unity Editor, but Getting error on iOS "ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null.”

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create Game Object instance when the screen is touched.
Also, I want to change this gameobject's model.

So I tried this code. If this code is working, I would add script changing prefab.
(Resources/PrefabName.prefab exists.)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LoadTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject spawnObject;

    void Start()
    {
        var obj = Instantiate(Resources.Load("PrefabName") as GameObject);
        obj.SetActive(false);
        spawnObject = obj;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.touchCount >= 1)
        {
            var obj = Instantiate(spawnObject);
            obj.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works on Unity Editor, but not on iOS.

```
ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null.

at UnityEngine.Object.CheckNullArgument (System.Object arg, System.String message) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

at UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

at LoadTest.Update () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

I don't understand this code is not working on iOS.

### Environment

Xcode(Version 11.6 (11E708))
iOS 13.6.1
Unity 2019.3.13f1

Comment: Not a Unity dev but i'd suggest separating `var obj = Instantiate(Resources.Load("PrefabName") as GameObject);` into 3 lines: 1) Assign `Resources.Load("PrefabName")` to a variable and check it's not null. 2) Check if `previouslyCreatedVariableFromStep1 is GameObject`, 3) pass it to `Instantiate` after these checks pass. Note that these are diagnostic steps, not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error in `Update()` so the problem is with this line:

```
var obj = Instantiate(prefab);
```

I don't see any assignments to `prefab` variable in your code.
I guess you need to `Instantiate` your `spawnObject` that you loaded, instantiated and assigned in `Start()`

```
var obj = Instantiate(spawnObject);
```

Make sure you won't destroy that GameObject later in the game or you will get null again. Better to cache reference to loaded object, not instantiated.

Even better not to use resources at all. Make reference to your prefab, assign it in the inspector and `Instantiate` it in code.